# Detect when the application is completely drawn and visible

Tags: android, android-layout

In short, I need to know when the launching of an application is completed, i.e. when exactly the application is drawn completely and visible to the user.

`ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener()` has single method - `onGlobalLayout()`.
I see that it is called multiple times, but I cannot detect the reason behind each specific call to it. Usually it is called 2-3 times, before the application becomes visible. Therefor I need to know if it will be called 2 or 3 or X times during each launch of the app, so I assume the reason for each call to `onGlobalLayout()` can help to determine this.

But I do not insist on using `onGlobalLayout()` if there is a better way to accomplish this task, so feel free to give other possibilities as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to wrong direction I think.

you should try `.post(Runnable action)`.

suppose linearLayout1 should be drawing at last, then you should try this...

```
linearLayout1.post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {// will be call when linearLayout1 will be completely loaded
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //you can write your code here
    }
});
```

Comment: This should work, because...it will add the Runnable to the end of the message queue for this View, so that the run() method will be executed after the view is drawn?
And is there a way to find which View will be drawn at the end?

Comment: @helleye i have no idea, but we should assume easily that which layout should be drawn at last... :-)

shouldn't we?

Comment: I cannot assume easily which one will be drawn at last :)
Anyway, I didn't see big difference by choosing different layouts to post them a runnable, so this solution fits the most to my needs.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is a better way. And you were very close to it.

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(myListener);
```

This callback will be called once the complete UI have been measured and laidout. The drawing operation will happen immedialy after this callback.

Special notes on usage:

- from the listener `onPreDraw` method you **must** return `true`, or else the drawing operation does not happen.
- if you only need to be called once, don't forget to remove the listener from inside the `onPreDraw` method. `view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(myListener);` or else you'll keep getting called again and again for every draw operation.

Comment: This answer seem to be helpful for my ultimate goal, but it does not answer really the question, because my question includes the drawing as well. However, comparing the time I got from `onPreDraw()` and the last `onGlobalLayout()` call, I am almost convinced the drawing itself is very slow on my device... Unless a better answer pops up in a few days, this would be the accepted one, as it should also be helpful for most of the people (even though it is not best suited for my specific case)

Comment: Well. I might have missed the point of the question, but as I said, the drawing on screen will happen as soon as this call back returns. Alternatively you have a 'onDrawListener' on the view tree observer that gets called immediately after the draw operation. That could be the answer you're looking for

Comment: `onDrawListener` was not called at all, and @Rumit answer was better for me. Still I think that this answer should suit best most of the others (my apps run on embedded device with Android), and is also useful and clearly described, but I can vote up only once...